# Why was my edit put in the review queue?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I am a 28K user on SO, and while looking at [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12014884/8946) saw that the link it contained was broken. So I located the correct link and update the answer with that and correct information on the JavaDoc. My edit was placed in the review queue, despite my rep and the fact that I was logged in at the time (or at least my icon and rep were showing in the top bar).

The review entry shows the edit was posted by an anonymous user. Huh?

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow certainly did not think you were not logged in, the [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5410932) you made is attributed to an anonymous user.

If you were logged out (session expired) after you loaded the page, the top bar would not have reflected that yet.

Comment: Well, it was about 2 minutes after loading the page, which I did because of activity on my own answer on the same page. Which activity I only saw because I was logged in.